# Calculate $\sin \frac \pi {10}$ with error bound of $10^{-4}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know there are similar posts about this question, but I have read them and it's still not clearly for me.

I have to calculate $\sin \frac \pi {10}$ with error bound of $10^{-4}$.

I know I have to use Maclaurin series $\sin x = x- \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac {x^5} {5!} + \dots$ and the Lagrange error bound, but I don't know how.

I know the Lagrange error bound is $\frac {f^{(n+1)}(c)} {(n+1)!} x^{n+1}$, but how do I know what is $f^{(n+1)}$?

I know that:

$f^{(4k+1)} = \cos x \\
f^{(4k+2)} = -\sin x \\
f^{(4k+3)} = -\cos x \\
f^{(4k+4)} = \sin x ,$

but how can I use that for calculating the error bound?

If someone can make me understand this, I will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "sinus" function?

Comment: All those things have absolute value at most $1$.  You get the bound from the growing denominator $n!$

Comment: $sin$ , Sorry about that.

Comment: @GregoryGrant But what about $f^{(n+1)}$ ?

Comment: Can you represent me the way to use the  lagrance error bound ?

Comment: @Noam That's what is never bigger than $1$.  So $|\sin(x)/n!|<1/n!$ no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: Ok, And what about $x^{n+1}$. Which $x$ should i use ?

Comment: @Noam Ah well you have to plug in $x=\pi/10$.  But that's also less than $1$, and remains less than one if you raise it to a power, so you can say the entire error term is no bigger than $1/(n+1)!$.

Comment: But you need to  have an approximation of $\pi$. How will the error on the value of $\pi$ propagate in the computations? It might be simpler to start from the known value of $\sin\frac\pi{10}=\frac14(\sqrt 5-1)$.

Comment: @Bernard True, the series approach will just give you the answer in terms of $\pi$.  But he does say he "knows" he has to use the series approach.

Comment: @Gregory Grant: In that case it's finer, but it won't be quite rigourous. Note $\sqrt 5$ can also be calculated with a series – albeit it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: @Stella *sine* derives from Latin *sinus* (which is also the name for sine in Russian, for example).

Comment: I dont understand.
For example, if i found that $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \leq  10^{-4}$ for $n \geq 10$

Should i calculate the series for the first $10$ elements ? 
$sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!}$

And therefore - $sin(\frac{\pi}{10}) = x - \frac{\frac{\pi}{10}^3}{3!} + \frac{\frac{\pi}{10}^5}{5!} - \frac{\frac{\pi}{10}^7}{7!} + \frac{\frac{\pi}{10}^3}{9!}$
How can i evaluate this ?

Comment: Yes you just need those five terms to get something within $10^{-4}$ of $\sin(\pi/10)$.  But you are now faced with the problem of approximating $\pi$.  So actually this is not a very clear question you've been asked.  Can you ask your teacher to clarify whether you can leave your answer in terms of $\pi$ or if you have to also approximate $\pi$.

Comment: Are you sure ?
$\frac{1}{6!} > 10^{-4}$
And yes, I have a decimal answer for that, therefore, I have to approximate $\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what is in the comments, your expressions for the derivatives are all bounded by $1$, so just replace $f^{(n+1)}$ by $1$ to get an upper bound for the error.  You need to find an $n$ such that $\frac {x^{n+1}}{n!}\lt 10^{-4}$.  You can also use the alternating series theorem, which says if you have an alternating series with the terms decreasing in absolute magnitude the error is smaller than the first neglected term and of the same sign.  In either case, you wind up computing your series until you find a term less than $10^{-4}$ and quitting.

Comment: "You can also use the alternating series theorem, which says if you have an alternating series with the terms decreasing in absolute magnitude the error is smaller than the first neglected term and of the same sign."


Can you explain that ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series